# Modifying a named range with openpyxl causing LibreOffice pivot table to stop using range

Tags: openpyxl, libreoffice-calc

I have a LibreOffice sheet with a pivot table with a source being a "Named range".
When I modify the named range using openpyxl, the source of the pivot table becomes a "Selection" which has the old value of the named range.

I am pretty sure the Range is properly defined, because formulas that use the range are computing the proper value based on the updated definition.  I am setting the name with

```
workbook.defined_names[name] = openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.DefinedName(name, ...)
```

I have also tried

```
workbook.defined_names[name].attr_text = ...
```

If I modify the Named range manually inside LibreOffice (and refresh the pivot table), all is well.

If I manually reset the source of the pivot table to be the modified named range, all is well

Thanks,

Comment: 'a LibreOffice sheet' or an Excel XLSX workbook that you use/modify with LibreOffice? Openpyxl will specifically reject any file that does not have the extension '.xlsx', '.xlsm', '.xltx' or '.xltm'. Also it cannot import '.ods' files renamed to 'xlsx' as the makeup is different to XLS[X]. Therefore if you are modifying the file with Openpyxl it must be of type XLS[X]